# Create my own method for DataFrames (python)

Tags: python, pandas, methods, module

So I wanted to create a module for my own projects and wanted to use methods. For example I wanted to do:

```
from mymodule import *
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4))
df.mymethod()
```

Thing is it seems I can't use `.myfunc()` since I think I can only use methods for the classes I've created. A work around is making `mymethod` a function and making it use `pandas.Dataframes` as a variable:

```
myfunc(df)
```

I don't really want to do this, is there anyway to implement the first one?

Comment: Why don't you want to make it a function? Otherwise you'll have to subclass or patch the data frame.

Comment: Depending on what the function does you may be able to use `apply`. For example `df.apply(myfunc)` I realize this doesn't create a new method, but perhaps it gets you what you need, at the very least you can do method chaining this way ` `df.apply(myfunc).apply(myotherfunc)`...

Comment: What about just using the `apply` method? How complex is your method?

Comment: As noted in an answer below, the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#) provides a "way to extend pandas objects without subclassing them" using the decorator `pandas.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor()`. There is a long list of extensions in the [pandas ecosystem](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/ecosystem.html#ecosystem) page.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Nice solution can be found in ffn package. What authors do:

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject
def your_fun(df):
    ...
PandasObject.your_fun = your_fun
```

After that your manual function "your_fun" becomes a method of pandas.DataFrame object and you can do something like

```
df.your_fun()
```

This method will be able to work with both DataFrame and Series objects

Comment: Does this technique or way of coding has a name? I am trying to understand how/why it works and not sure I grasp it.

Comment: @monkeyintern There is "monkey-patching" name for it in outdated docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/faq.html#adding-features-to-your-pandas-installation , however I found not pandas specific, but general way to add methods here https://medium.com/@mgarod/dynamically-add-a-method-to-a-class-in-python-c49204b85bd6

Comment: After experimenting, this seems to add this under all Pandas object, including Series (columns), maybe not what you want, as "self" - here "df" is then not a dataframe, but a Series... You would then have to stop the user from using a method in a place you have put it. The Pandas API now lets you extend in other ways. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html Take a look at pandichef's answer.

Comment: Note that this can also be done with an anonymous function, (e.g. `pd.Series.vc = lambda x: x.value_counts(dropna=False)`)

Answer (score 12):

If you *really* need to add a method to a `pandas.DataFrame` you can inherit from it.  Something like:

**mymodule:**

```
import pandas as pd

class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def mymethod(self):
        """Do my stuff"""
```

**Use mymodule:**

```
from mymodule import *
df = MyDataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4))
df.mymethod()
```

**To preserve your custom dataframe class:**

`pandas` routinely returns new dataframes when performing operations on dataframes.  So to preserve your dataframe class, you need to have `pandas` return your class when performing operations on an instance of your class.  That can be done by providing a `_constructor` property like:

```
class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDataFrame

    def mymethod(self):
        """Do my stuff"""
```

**Test Code:**

```
class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDataFrame

df = MyDataFrame([1])
print(type(df))
df = df.rename(columns={})
print(type(df))
```

**Test Results:**

```
<class '__main__.MyDataFrame'>
<class '__main__.MyDataFrame'>
```

Comment: plus one for effort.  But won't this be difficult because pandas will just return a dataframe in most cases.  You have to do some additional trickery to override every pd.DataFrame method that returns `pd.DataFrame`.  Otherwise, this is a one use method and you are back to a `pdDataFrame`... most likely.

Comment: @piRSquared, you are correct as usual.  But there appears to be an easy workaround.

Answer (score 12):

This topic is well documented as of Nov 2019: [Extending pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html)

Note that the most obvious technique - Ivan Mishalkin's monkey patching - was actually removed at some point in the official documentation... probably for good reason.

Monkey patching works fine for small projects, but there is a serious drawback for a large scale project: IDEs like Pycharm can't introspect the patched-in methods.  So if one right clicks "Go to declaration", Pycharm simply says "cannot find declaration to go to".  It gets old fast if you're an IDE junkie.

I confirmed that Pycharm CAN introspect both the "custom accessors" and "subclassing" methods discussed in the official documentation.

Comment: This is now the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Ivan Mishalkins handy solution in our in-house python library extensively. At some point I thought,  it would be better to use his solution in form of a decorator. The only restriction is that **the first argument of decorated function must be a DataFrame**:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from functools import wraps
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

def as_method(func):
    """
    This decrator makes a function also available as a method.
    The first passed argument must be a DataFrame.
    """

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*deepcopy(args), **deepcopy(kwargs))

    setattr(PandasObject, wrapper.__name__, wrapper)

    return wrapper


@as_method
def augment_x(DF, x):
    """We will be able to see this docstring if we run ??augment_x"""
    DF[f"column_{x}"] = x

    return DF
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2]})
df
   A
0  1
1  2

df.augment_x(10)
   A  column_10
0  1         10
1  2         10
```

As you can see, the original DataFrame is not changed. As if there is a `inplace = False`

```
df
   A
0  1
1  2
```

You can still use the `augment_x` as a simple function:

```
augment_x(df, 2)
    A   column_2
0   1   2
1   2   2
```