# pandas: How to add a method to a class that you did not define?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a `compute()` method to all `pandas.DataFrame` objects and the `compute` just does

```
def compute(self):
  return self
```

But how do I add a method to a class that is defined in a package?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.compute = compute` Although, be careful, without a good knowledge of the code base monkey-patching may not work cleanly, especially in a complex code base.

Comment: One option is to use a virtual environment and you can install [tag:pandas] and then manually add your compute method to the [tag:pandas] module. If you mess up the module, you can uninstall and then reinstall. It's all contained to the virtual environment too. Just one option.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject
def compute(df):
    ...
PandasObject.compute = compute

df.compute()
```

Please be warned that you might overwrite some existing methods, which is extremely undesirable, unless you know what you are doing. Refer to this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504068/create-my-own-method-for-dataframes-python) for other approaches.