# Pandas evalassign method?

Tags: pandas, eval

I have a series of DataFrame transformations which evaluate certain variable values within a DataFrame and generate new variable values. I could do this as I see it in two ways. I need the most concise and readable method possible as we are going to need to do this operation for about 2000 variables and values.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : range(0,10)})
df['B'] = df.A**2-9

# method 1
df.loc[df.A < df.B, 'C'] = "A less than B"
df.loc[df.A == df.B, 'C'] = "A equals B"
df.loc[df.A > df.B, 'C'] = "A greater than B"

# method 2
selector = df.eval('A < B')
df.loc[selector, 'C'] = "A less than B"

selector = df.eval('A == B')
df.loc[selector, 'C'] = "A equals B"

selector = df.eval('A > B')
df.loc[selector, 'C'] = "A greater than B"
```

Neither of these methods is ideal as the first has most of the action happening in the middle of the dataframe `[]`s and gets really confusing when you have a lot of conditions (due to a ton of visual artifacts). Method 2 is a little more readable as it draws the eyes to the end of the selector statement and the value assigned statements which is wear most of the action is happening. Since most of the logic is internal to the DataFrame the more concise notation is also helpful.

In response to this I have written a couple of my own methods which do the same thing slightly more tersely.

```py
class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDataFrame

    def recode(self, variable, **kwargs):
        for v in kwargs:
            selector = self.eval(kwargs[v])
            self.loc[selector, variable] = v
        return self

    
    def code(self, variable, mydict):
        for v in mydict:
            selector = self.eval(mydict[v])
            self.loc[selector, variable] = v
        return self
```

To define my class and two methods `recode` and `code` [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504068/create-my-own-method-for-dataframes-python/53630084).

```py
df = MyDataFrame({'A' : range(0,10)})
df['B'] = df.A**2-9

df.recode('C', AgtB = 'A > B', AltB = 'A < B', AeqB = 'A == B')
df.code('D', {'A less than B' : 'A < B', 'A equals B' : 'A==B', 'A greater than B' : "A > B"})
```

Questions

1. Am I reinventing the wheel?
2. Am I making some fundamental error in how I am approaching this?

Comment: If readability is your goal and you can sacrifice performance then I would just create a python function with your standard if, elif, else language and pass it into `apply`.  If performance is your goal then `np.select` or `np.where` is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

How about `np.select`:

```
df['C'] = np.select([ df.eval('A < B'),df.eval('A == B'),df.eval('A > B')],
                    ["A less than B", "A equals B","A greater than B"])
```

which should be a little faster than several `loc` assignments.