# How to split the groups and apply a function in Pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a dataframe defined as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar'],
                   'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'C' : ['mean', 'halfmean', 'mean', 'halfmean', 'mean', 'halfmean', 'mean', 'halfmean']})
```

I would like to aggregate the `B` for each groups of `A` based on a condition in `C`. What is the effective way to do it?

Note: `C` is same for a group. That is, I need mean of all numbers for `foo` and mean of half of nlargest number in `bar`.

```
grouped = df.groupby('A')
????
```

Expected result

```
foo 4 #(1 + 3 + 5 + 7)/4
bar 7 #(6 + 8)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to calculate mean and halfman separately, and then combine them:

```py
grouped_mean = df[df['C'] == 'mean'][['A', 'B']].groupby('A').mean().reset_index()

grouped_halfmean = df[df['C'] == 'halfmean'][['A', 'B']].groupby('A').mean().reset_index()
grouped_halfmean['B'] = grouped_halfmean['B'] / 2

result = pd.concat([grouped_mean, grouped_halfmean])
```

Comment: thanks for response. I wanted the mean of all element or mean of first N half of the elements based on the C column

Comment: Forgive my inattention. I corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

def custom_agg(grp):
    if grp['C'].iloc[0]=='mean':
        return grp['B'].mean()
    elif grp['C'].iloc[0]=='halfmean':
        n=len(grp)//2  #Note this is lower bound if you want upper bound you can simply do n=(len(grp)+1)//2
        return grp['B'].nlargest(n).mean()

df=pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar'],
                   'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'C' : ['mean', 'halfmean', 'mean', 'halfmean', 'mean', 'halfmean', 'mean', 'halfmean']})

group=df.groupby('A')
res=group.apply(custom_agg)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
A
bar    7.0
foo    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey patch a custom function and use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

def halfmean(g):
    L = len(g)//2
    return g.nlargest(L).sum()/L

PandasObject.halfmean = halfmean

out = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda g: g['B'].agg(g['C'].iloc[0]))
```

Output:

```
A
bar    7.0
foo    4.0
dtype: float64
```

##### monkey patched `halfmean`:

After [monkey-patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), all `DataFrames`/`Series` have the new (rudimentary) `halfmean` method:

```
df['B'].halfmean()
# 6.5
```

To remove it:

```
del PandasObject.halfmean
```

See [create my own method for DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504068/create-my-own-method-for-dataframes-python) for more details.

---

##### without monkey-patching

you can also use a simple dictionary, try the custom functions first, if it doesn't exist, fallback to numpy/pandas methods:

```
def halfmean(g):
    L = len(g)//2
    return g.nlargest(L).sum()/L

custom_funcs = {'halfmean': halfmean}

out = (df.groupby('A')
         .apply(lambda g: g['B'].agg(custom_funcs.get(g['C'].iloc[0],
                                                      g['C'].iloc[0])))
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

As a trick you could use numpy method `array_split` to cut arrays in `2` parts and then apply `mean()` to the second part, like it's showed in the following script :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar'],
                   'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'C' : ['mean', 'halfmean', 'mean', 'halfmean', 'mean', 'halfmean', 'mean', 'halfmean']})

r = (df.groupby('A')
       .apply(lambda g:g['B'].mean() if g['C'].eq('mean').all() \
              else np.array_split(g, 2)[1]['B'].mean())
     )

print(r)
```

```
A
bar    7.0
foo    4.0
dtype: float64
```